# Add a field to a document in raven 3.5 where the property doesn't exist

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravendb-3.5

In my instance of raven3.5 I have a collection and some documents have an extra property due to a change in the document structure. Now I need to query on that property but many older documents don't have it.

How can I patch the collection and add the property to documents that don't have it? Or create a query that will get the documents that don't have the specific property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The below is what I know works for RavenDB Server **4.2 and up**:

**Option 1 - using static index**

Create a **[static index](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/static-indexes-overview)** ('MyIndex') with the following **[map](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/map-index)** method:

```
from i in docs.Items
select new {
    Name = i.Name
}
```

Then query the index as follows:

Return all 'Items' that do not have 'Name':

```
from index 'MyIndex'
where true and not exists(Name)
```

**Option 2 - using auto-index:**

First, run the following query which will 'create' the **[auto-index](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/auto-indexes/auto-map-index1)** for you:

```
from Items
where exists(Name)
```

After that, you can query the following to get results:

```
from Items
where true and not exists(Name)
```

=================================================

A **[patch](https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#patching-documents)** script is made up of the **query part** and the **update part**
So use the following to add the missing property to docs that don't have it:

```
from Items
where true and not exists(Name)
update {
   this.Name = "value"
}
```